# Jenkins pipeline stage inside another stage based on if condition

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to write a stages inside another stage based on if condition. I am not able to come up with a solution. Can anyone guide on this

```
         stages {
             stage('Example') {
             steps {
                script {
                if(!(fileExists("c:/test.txt")))
                {
                    echo "Inside if"
                    stage('1') {
                       echo "stage1"
                    }
                    stage('2') {
                       echo "stage2"
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                 stage('else stage') {
                       echo "else stage1"
                    }
                 }
               }
             }
           }
         }
```

Comment: Not possible with declarative pipeline. Only possible with scripted pipeline. But better be aware that conditional execution of stages ***will*** cause issues with visualization, in both classic and BlueOcean UI. Stages should always execute in order, at most you can abort early.

Comment: I would think you could use this: https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#when

Comment: Thanks @MattSchuchard solved by using when as below,                                                       when {
                expression { 
                    return !(fileExists("c:/test.txt"))
                }
            }

Comment: @Karthik Do you want me to write up an answer for you around that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me.

```
when { 
    expression  
    { 
      return !(fileExists("c:/test.txt"))
    } 
}
```